# get the coordinates of a point from google street

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using google maps api in javascript, and when i am not in google street mode i am using this code to get the lat/long of a point:

```
        function addClickListener() {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "click", function (event) {
            var latFromMap = event.latLng.lat();
            var lngFromMap = event.latLng.lng();
            // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
            document.getElementById("lat").value = latFromMap;
            document.getElementById("long").value = lngFromMap;
        });
    }
```

its work good, but i want to have a option to get the coordinates when i am in the google street mode, so i will be able to click on a point and i will get the lat/long like i have know in the regular map... some one know if its possible?

thanks

Comment: Maybe some [Google-Fu](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/P0Mp46IOews) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no click-event for a streetView, but you may observe the click-event of the node that holds the map, and when it occurs check if the streetView is visible:

```
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'click', function(){
          if(map.getStreetView().getVisible()){
            //streetview is selected,do something
            alert(map.getStreetView().getPosition().toString());
          }
        });
```

Note: this will give you the position of the streetView, the exact coordinates of the click-event may not be retrieved in streetView-mode, because this requires a projection, which is not available.